# what determines where applications go when connecting another monitor

Tags: gnome

There is no rhyme or reason where applications show when connecting a second monitor. sometimes, for example, Opera Browser automatically goes to the second monitor, but sometimes it stays on the prime monitor. Other applications also do this.
Is there any way to set a policy on this?
Ubuntu 20.02.01 5.13.30.0 kernel.
The second monitor is hdmi , sometimes set to primary on one monitor, other times set to secondary on another monitor, which always works for me. It is mostly this secondary monitor that has this issue.

Comment: Is this stock Ubuntu? Or a derivative like Kubuntu?

Comment: Please clarify your release details; Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format, and no release occurred in 2020-February (20.02) so is it Ubuntu? or a Ubuntu-based system?  Please be accurate & precise with details.

Comment: There is some algorithm behind it, which however is obscure and not user configurable. Little control by the user, unfortunatelly.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: If your system reports as 20.04.1 still; I'd suggest applying security fixes as a fully-upgraded system reports as 20.04.4 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/02/25/ubuntu-20-04-4-lts-released/) and 20.04.1 implies you've not applied security fixes & upgraded packages for more than a year (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/02/05/ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date; but installed systems upgraded a week+ before that).  *Also please correct your question as it's showing invalid release details*.

Comment: actually I just reckecked, perhaps I was on the other machine... it still is 5.13.0-30-generic . I would have done some updates within 6 weeks ago. thanks for the tip, though I have had the best security the 1 mar to 8 mar, no internet following natural disasters.

Comment: I beg to differ , I have done a do-release-upgrade Checking for a new Ubuntu release
'There is no development version of an LTS available.
 'Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.  still on 20.4.1

Comment: do-release-upgrade -d

Comment: off topic but this upgrade which totally screwed up my system. I will have to do a clean install. I have resorted to a clonezilla restore meanwhile.